# Theme Options Menu Item - Permission Issue

Tags: themes, customization, menus, options

I am trying to create a theme options menu item for my custom theme. However, when I add the following piece of code in the functions.php file...

```
add_menu_page('Page title', 'Asteria', 'manage_options', 'ThemeOptions', 'my_magic_function');
```

It gives me the following error when clicking on the menu item...

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

The entire folder, and all contents are 777'd. I am logged in as an administrator. I have tried this on 2 different servers. One of the servers is running a network of blogs (the preferred server), the other is just a single blog setup.

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Comment: Can it be something in the my_magic_function function? Your code works for me if I hook it to the right action (admin_menu).

Comment: Any chance you can post the my_magic_function code and the action it's hooked to?

Comment: You need to add that page inside a callback on `admin_menu` as is shown in [the example on the codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page#Example).

Comment: Ah-ha, I must have skipped over this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme Options should use the `edit_theme_options` permission, *not* the `manage_options` permission. The former is the permission intended for editing Theme options; the latter is the permission intended for editing **site** options.

Comment: Perfect! It ended up being a combination of using the admin_menu hook (I was just calling a random action before) and the edit_theme_options permission. Thanks a ton for the help!